# Can anyone identify these characters? (Characters identified: 照菜科)

Tags: characters, character-identification

Can anyone help me identify these characters, I'm having a difficult time even finding the radicals due to the photo quality. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: The site is for learning but not character recognition. Please at least show some of your effort and give more context.

Comment: I think we need a better context to determine which characters are they.

Answer (score 1):

The characters look like 照菜科. I’m unable to make sense of that without more context.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with following cooking instructions?

Comment: Yes, these are the characters I actually found them not long after posting. Thank you for your help, they are from placards for an airplane.